# How to prevent a class from seeing DLL file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dll, conflict

A colleague of mine has written a DLL file for me to use called "Security.dll".

I have added this to my project and it is working ok, but I have a class which utilizes `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` which seems to use a seperate DLL file in in my System32 folder, also called "Security.dll"

Therefore, when I try and send an email, I get the following error:

> {"Unable to find an entry point named 'EnumerateSecurityPackagesW' in DLL 'security.dll'.":""}

Is there a way to instruct this particular class to ignore the DLL file, or do I need to ask my colleague to change the name?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to [sign these assemblies with a strong name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, I found this article which went into a bit more depth than the one on MSDN - http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/article.php/c4643/Giving-a-NET-Assembly-a-Strong-Name.htm

Comment: @JMK - Glad to have been able to help